# Admob not blocking dating ads in my app

Tags: android, admob

I made an app using Android Studio and integrated Admob to it.

In the Admob settings, I blocked the ads like Dating, Sexual & Reproductive Health, etc..

[image]

The problem is that I am still getting dating ads in my app.

What could be the problem ?

Comment: Maybe this is an admob issue. You should ask in their Google group, or file a bug report, or it's the advertiser's fault when we wants to bypass some content checks or something (although I'm not sure if Google checks the ad content first)

Comment: yep agree with @Bevor , you should notify google group about this.